# In mongoDb, how do you remove a array element on specific index position?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

In the following example, assume the document is in the db.people collection.

I want to remove an element of index 3 from item list. How can I remove the specific element at index 3?

```
{
    "_id": "6527c64e539e51befb0db39c",
    "category": "fruits",
    "dataType": "string",
    "isList": true,
    "item": [
        null,
        "mango",
        "banana",
        "kiwi",
        "orange",
        null,
        "watermelon"
    ]
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
db.people.update({_id:ObjectId('6527c64e539e51befb0db39c')}, {$unset : {"item.3" : 1 }}) 
db.people.update({_id:ObjectId('6527c64e539e51befb0db39c')}, {$pull : {"item" : null}})
```

Result I got:
It removed all the null values from the item array field.

```
{
    "_id": "6527c64e539e51befb0db39c",
    "category": "fruits",
    "dataType": "string",
    "isList": true,
    "item": [
        "mango",
        "banana",
        "kiwi",
        "orange",
        "watermelon"
    ]
}
```

What result I want:

```
{
    "_id": "6527c64e539e51befb0db39c",
    "category": "fruits",
    "dataType": "string",
    "isList": true,
    "item": [
        null,
        "mango",
        "banana",
        "orange",
        null,
        "watermelon"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$slice` to get first and later halves of the array before and after the element. Then return it with `$concatArrays` and `$set` for the update.

```js
db.collection.update({
  _id: ObjectId("6527c64e539e51befb0db39c")
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "item": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          {
            "$slice": [
              "$item",
              3
            ]
          },
          {
            "$slice": [
              "$item",
              4,
              {
                "$size": "$item"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JRLQRDzrdar)

Comment: Thankyou so much @ray for your valuable time to consider my problem. The solution you provided is working as charm. It is working excellently for my case.